# R coerce data frame to numeric

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric

RandomForest has returned object, prd, which is class numeric with indices:

```
> prd
      298       252       373       117         0        16       442        74 
4397.9232 1826.1264 1787.1963 1388.8097 1075.7217  873.9856 1602.7068 1775.1237 
class(prd)
[1] "numeric"
```

I want to do a correlation test, which means getting obs in the same format. Currently, obs is a one-column data frame:

```
> obs
       e2004MeanY
298       4261
252       1821
373       1710
117       1138
```

How do I convert obs to the correct format? I can't figure out how to tie the indices to the values in a numeric.

Comment: ? `obs` looks like it has two columns.  Is the first col of numbers the row names?

Comment: `> dim(obs)
    [1] 122   1`

It only has one column, the left 'column' are the indices

Comment: What do you get with `str(prd)`?

Comment: `> str(prd)
 Named num [1:122] 4398 1826 1787 1389 1076 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:122] "298" "252" "373" "117" ...
`

Comment: What's wrong with `obs[, 1]`?

Comment: I guess that works, but I lose the indices that way - I assumed this would be simple. Is there no easy way to convert this?

Comment: What code are you using to do the correlation test?

Comment: @Zug - who cares about the names? If you want them on the vector, just add them back. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset a data frame using `[` which, as the default is `drop = TRUE` will drop the empty dimension thus going from a 1 column data frame to a numeric vector. E.g.

```
R> obs <- data.frame(e2004MeanY = c(4261,1821,1712,1138))
R> rownames(obs) <- c(268,252,373,117)
R> 
R> (obs1 <- obs[, 1]) ## equiv of: obs[, 1, drop = TRUE]
[1] 4261 1821 1712 1138
R> class(obs1)
[1] "numeric"
```

If the losing of the row names is an issue then add them back as the `names` of the vector:

```
R> names(obs1) <- rownames(obs)
R> obs1
 268  252  373  117 
4261 1821 1712 1138
```

Of course, this isn't an issue if you use a temporary object when you call `cor()`, for example:

```
cor(prd, obs[, 1])
```